# React problem fetching data Uncaught TypeError: products.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I want to fetch data in React from given API(link is censored in code example).
Fetching data works in vanilla javascript.
But i need to do the same thing in react but i get these errors.

first error - Uncaught TypeError: products.map is not a function.
second error - The above error occurred in the  component:

Console response screenshot
[image]

React code (DOES NOT WORK)

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function DataFetching() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadProducts = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get("https://CENSORED/");
      setProducts(response.data);
      console.log(response);
    };
    loadProducts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        {products.map((data) => (
          <h4>{data.product.name}</h4>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Vanilla JS code (THIS CODE WORKS)

```
async function start() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://CENSORED/`);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    renderData(data);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("There was a problem fetching data.");
  }
}
start();

function renderData(data) {
  document.getElementById("products").innerHTML = `
  
    <p>${data.product.name}</p>
    <p>${data.product.reviews.rating}</p>
   `;
}
```

Comment: In your vanilla example, it looks like there is no `data` object on your response. Also, it looks like your response in an object instead of an array.

Comment: If `products.map` is not a function then `products` is not an array.  So what is it?  Log its value to the console so you can see what it contains.  When you logged `response` to the console, what did it contain?

Comment: @David i edited the post and added an image of the response

Comment: @Kikoanno: So... `response.data` is *not an array*.  Nowhere in the working code are you expecting any data to be an array.  Why are you expecting it to be an array in React?

Comment: @David what should i change so that i dont fetch it as an array?

Comment: You aren't fetching it as an array. It says "product" (not plural) and it's a single object. `{}.map()` is undefined. The reason vanilla works is because you're treating it like it is, a single object, and _not_ calling `map` on it. So do the same in React--don't call `map` on the object and directly access `.name`.

Comment: @ggorlen how can i access the .name without calling map?
i tried just like this   <div>
        <p>{products.product.name}</p>
      </div>
but no luck

Comment: That seems like it should work but I'm trusting your screenshot because I can't run this code (ideally, mock the response and make a complete, runnable snippet...). `console.log(products)` is your friend--it'll show you exactly what you're working with. Here's a cheat: `console.log(JSON.stringify(products))`, then plop it into [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json/68460317#68460317) and it'll give you the code if you click on the property you want.

Answer (score 0):

In the original code you're treating the response as an object, not an array:

```
data.product.name
```

Specifically, an object with a property called `product`, which has a property called `name`.

So... Why are you suddenly expecting *the same data* to now be an array?  If `products` in the new code is the same data as `data` in the original code, then it would have **the same properties**:

```
<div className="App">
  <p>{products.product.name}</p>
  <p>{products.product.reviews.rating}</p>
</div>
```

Basically, there's no reason to expect React or Axios to internally convert objects into arrays.

(As an aside... `products` is a poor naming choice for an object which contains a single "product".  You appear to have confused yourself with your variable names and assumed something was an array simply because you pluralized its name.  Naming is important.)